# how to undo installlin youtub-dl and python3-pip

Tags: python3, youtube

i have question i install pyhon3 pip and then I install youtube-dl

```
sudo install apt python3-pip
```

```
sudo pip3  install youtube-dl
```

how i can uninstall youtube-dl and undo installing pyhon3 as pip  i get that WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager

Answer (score 1):

Please read and try to understand this:

> Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager",

i.e. it is telling you to not run it as `sudo pip ...`,

I'd say `python -m pip ...`  is a lot better, no `sudo` required.

Also; `python -m pip help` will tell a lot of relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command on your terminal:

```
sudo apt remove python3-pip youtube-dl
```

. This will remove both python3-pip and youtube-dl.

Comment: This will not remove youtube-dl.